# Read all emails from outlook

Tags: python, outlook

I wanted to check how can I read all emails from outlook in python

I am using below code, but this code is reading only first mail,

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.Body
subject = message.Subject
categories = message.Categories
print(body_content)
print(subject)
print(categories)
```

I tried to find a way so that we can read all emails but unable to get a solution, is anyone know how we can read all emails and store in the database.

Comment: You should also check your security settings in Office.  Sometimes programmatic access has been disable and you can only get metadata from each email.  File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Programmatic Access

Comment: @James, Thanks for your inputs. As suggested will check programmatic access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate through the messages object to get all email content.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
'''message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.Body
subject = message.Subject
categories = message.Categories
print(body_content)
print(subject)
print(categories)'''

for message in messages:
    print(message.Subject)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am get to get required results using your answer